# STM32 printing to serial via UART

Tags: c, stm32, uart

I'm using the STM `B-L475E-IOT01A2` discovery board and I'm trying to get it to print a value to its serial port via `uart`. So far I haven't been successful. It builds fine, and doesn't error (tested with some LEDs) but nothing prints to the serial (tested with `screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600`). Here is my code, most of it is auto generated by CubeMX.

```
/** file: usart.c **/

void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};
  if(uartHandle->Instance==USART1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 0 */

  /** Initializes the peripherals clock
  */
    PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1;
    PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_SYSCLK;
    if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    /* USART1 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration
    PA9     ------> USART1_TX
    PA10     ------> USART1_RX
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}
```

```
/** file: main.c **/
int main(void)
{
  HAL_UART_MspInit(&huart1);
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  while(1) {
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)"Testing 123", 11, 100);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `stty < /dev/ttyACM0` say? Are HW flow control and parity check disabled? Did you try another UART which is not connected to ST-Link instead of UART1?

Comment: Always use a logic analyzer when debugging communication protocols on the wire.

Comment: I don't know what the actual problem is, but you are not supposed to call HAL_UART_MspInit yourself.  This is a callback, you define it and the HAL calls it at the appropriate point itself.

Comment: Also, maybe the problem is related to the UART/USART distinction.  I think the UART library should work on a USART hardware instance, but try switching everything to the USART library and seeing if it works.